# Notice: Undefined index al enviar arrays por ajax

Tags: php, ajax, array

me pasa algo raro, he utilizado el mismo codigo en otra parte de mi proyecto y funciona perfectamente pero al pasar array por ajax estoy recibiendo "notice Undefined index" he utilizado diferentes variantes que he encontrado para pasar arrays correctamente usando AJAX pero ninguna parece funcionar, sugerencias?

Codigo JS

```
$(document).on('click', '#verificarImp', function(){
var r = $('table tr').length;
var item1 = [];
var item2 = [];
var item3 = [];
var w;

for (w = 1; w < r ; w++) {
item1[w-1] = document.getElementById('idCodigo_'+w).value;
item2[w-1] = document.getElementById('idDetalle_'+w).value;
item3[w-1] = document.getElementById('idCantidad_'+w).value;
}
  $.ajax({
     url:"presolicitud_me.php",
     method:"POST",
     data:{item1:item1, item2:item2, item3:item3},
     success:function(resultado){
     if(resultado){
       alert(resultado);
     }
     }
  });
});
```

al hacer click en un boton, colecta los valores de una tabla dinamica en arrays y los envia a la pagina "presolicitud_me.php"

codigo PHP

```
<?php
$codigo = $_POST['item1'];
$detalle = $_POST['item2'];
$cantidad = $_POST['item3'];

var_dump($detalle);
?>
```

otra rareza es que si le coloco un alert a success puedo ver correctamente la ejecucion del codigo PHP pero en la pagina como tal no esta funcionando.

Comment: Hola!, quién te dice "notice Undefined index" el javascript al click o el php al procesar? si es el javascript puedes revisar que línea marca el error

Comment: Puede decirno cual es el index que te marca error ?

Comment: Necesitas escribir un código coherente. Preguntaría ¿que espera en respuesta la petición Ajax? Un `var_dump` no te sirve para manejar adecuadamente el `success`, a lo sumo necesitas un JSON con una clave `status` por ejemplo que sea true o false, entonces podrás evaluar así : `if (respuesta.status){...` tu problema es de coherencia en el código, nada más.

Comment: Por qué volvés a cargar la página PHP cuándo devuelve la función? Creo que ese es tu error, al recargar no vuelve a enviar los datos.

Comment: @Christian Gonzales. El notice undefined index lo da la pagina PHP

Comment: @srJJ todos los indices marcan error

Comment: @A. Cedano, el var_dump es para comprobar si el array esta enviando los datos correctamente (y lo esta)

Comment: @Lunestudio solo lo añadi para probar, pero tienes razon esta de mas ahi, voy a quitarlo

Comment: Entonces ¿cuál es el problema en sí?

Comment: ¿Cual es el problema?

Comment: me parece que @Lunestudio tiene razon, despues de enviar los datos quiero trabajar con los mismos en la pagina PHP el problema es que al recargar la pagina PHP no vuelve a enviar los datos, entonces el problema es como cargar la pagina PHP con los datos que he enviado sin recargar la pagina PHP

Comment: entonces no debes usasr ajax, ya que ajax es una peticion, por ende ella va y vuelve con resultados, lo que debes hacer es generar un Form desde jquery y enviar los datos y ahi si podras manipular los datos desde ahi

Comment: Debes informarte sobre cómo funciona Ajax. Puedes perfectamente enviar los datos y trabajar con ellos en PHP, el *quid*  de la cuestión es que **el archivo al que envías los datos desde Ajax no puede ser el mismo que el archivo actual, sino otro distinto**, me refiero al archivo que pones en el parámetrol `url`  de la petición Ajax.

Comment: @A. Cedano voy a buscar información, ya estaba creando el formulario con javascript, ya que solo necesito enviar 3 arrays y no es tan largo, pero si hay otras opciones vale la pena revisar, gracias a todos!

Comment: @KanguroAndino podrías agregar tu form y decirnos en qué archivo lo tenés?